# Changes of Cohomologies in small resolution

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a singular complex variety of dimension $3$, whose singular locus is only a node! Suppose there exists a small resolution
\begin{equation}
\pi~:~\hat{X} \rightarrow X
\end{equation} 
which replaces the node in $X$ by a $\mathbb{P}^1$. Suppose $\hat{X}$ is Calabi-Yau, which I mean it is smooth and has trivial canonical sheaf, I try to show the following,

If $\mathcal{F}$ is a locally free sheaf of rank $3$ on $X$, since the singularity is so mild and could be resolved by a small resolution, the cohomology should not change (much), i.e.

\begin{equation}
h^i(X,\mathcal{F})=h^i(\hat{X},\pi^*\mathcal{F}),~0\leq i \leq 3
\end{equation}

I try to use projection formula, which implies
\begin{equation}
R^i\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\hat{X}} \otimes\mathcal{F} \cong R^i \pi_*(\pi^*\mathcal{F})
\end{equation}
then $ R^i \pi_*(\pi^*\mathcal{F})(X)=H^i(\hat{X},\pi^*\mathcal{F})$, but I do not know how to compute the left hand side $(R^i\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\hat{X}} \otimes\mathcal{F})(X)$, anyone got any ideas how to prove this?

edit:From the advice below by MooS, using Grauert-Riemenschneider vanishing theorem, 
\begin{equation}
0=R^i \pi_* \omega_{\hat{X}}=R^i \pi_* \mathcal{O}_{\hat{X}}, ~\forall ~i >0
\end{equation}
thus we have 
\begin{equation}
R^i \pi_*(\pi^*\mathcal{F})=0,~\forall ~i >0
\end{equation}

Is a node rational singularity? Could this imply $\pi_* \mathcal{O}_{\hat{X}} \cong \mathcal{O}_X$? Suppose this is true, we have 
\begin{equation}
\pi_*(\pi^*\mathcal{F}) \cong \mathcal{F}
\end{equation}
Then we got $H^0(X,\mathcal{F}) \cong H^0(\hat{X},\pi^*\mathcal{F})$, next we use Leray spectral sequence, so the $E_2$ term 
\begin{equation}
H^q(X,R^p \pi_*(\pi^* \mathcal{F})) ~~~\text{abuts}~~~H^{p+q}(\hat{X},\pi_*\mathcal{F}) 
\end{equation}
Then only when $p=0$, $H^q(X,R^p \pi_*(\pi^* \mathcal{F}))$ is not $0$, does this imply the following isomorphism?
\begin{equation}
H^q(X,\pi_*(\pi^* \mathcal{F})) \cong H^{q}(\hat{X},\pi_*\mathcal{F}) 
\end{equation}
Then this would finish the proof!

Comment: For the computation of the push-forward, note the following:

Grauert-Riemenschneider vanishing implies $0=R^i \pi_* \omega_{\hat X} = R^i \pi_* \mathcal O_{\hat X}$ for $i>0$, i.e. $R^i\pi_*\pi^*\mathcal F = 0$ for $i>0$.

Comment: In this situation, is it true that $\pi_* \mathcal{O}_{\hat{X}} \cong \mathcal{O}_X$?(Is the node rational singularity? which might imply this!) Then we have $\pi_*(\pi^* \mathcal{F}) \cong \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: @MooS Thank you, I have edited the arguments above, is it OK?